# jQuery $(this) VS event.currentTarget

Tags: jquery

I am practicing some jQuery and have some issue that return the expected result. As I understand it, to target the selected element inside an event handler, we can pass the event to the callback function and use `event.currentTarget` instead.

So this:

```
$('.nav-menu').on('mouseleave', ()=>{
  $('.nav-menu').hide();
});
```

Would become this:

```
$('.nav-menu').on('mouseleave', (event)=>{
  $(event.currentTarget).hide();
});
```

If I understand this link ([W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp)) correct, the same thing could be achieved using `$('this')`:

```
$('.nav-menu').on('mouseleave', ()=>{
  $(this).hide();
});
```

In this last case, the callback function does not need to be passed the event as parameter. It's also shorter, so that's cool :)

But it doesn't work. I'm not sure why.
The first 2 solutions work fine.

Advice anyone? 
Thanks!

Comment: This difference is due to your use of arrow functions as they maintain the outer scope. See the duplicate for more information. Also, please don't use W3Schools as a reference. Their articles are often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong. MDN is far more comprehensive and accurate: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: In the last one, if you change `()=>` to `function()` it will work because of how the arrow functions work.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for the tips. It was my first question to stackoverflow. I will refer to MDN from now on.

Comment: @BlueEyedBehemoth Hah.. Many thanks. That works. :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.